# Nginx SSL + Varnish + Nginx HTTP server, .css and .js files URL's are getting rewritten to http

Tags: nginx, varnish

I am using Nginx as an SSL terminator that serves requests to Varnish, and then Varnish passes the cached data to Another Nginx Vhost. Everything works well so far, but for some reason, only .css and .js files are being rewritten to http instead of https. I have been looking for solutions, including  [https://www.rsreese.com/redirect-http-to-https-using-varnish/](http://this%20one)

But it does not rewrite the assets URL's on my case. Can someone shed some light here ?

This is the NGINX conf : There are one redirect from www to non wwww, a server listening on port 80 that rewrites the URL to the HTTPS version, the SSL terminator server that passes to Varnish and then back to the last server wich is the regular HTTP server.

```
    server {
        server_name www.domain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name domain.com;
        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    server {

            listen 443 ssl;

            server_name domain.com;
            access_log  off;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/cert_chain.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

            if ($allow = no) {
            return 403;
            }
            if ($bad_referer) {
            return 444;
            }
            proxy_redirect     off;

            location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            }
    }

    server {

            listen 8081;
            root /var/wwwd/domain.com/wordpress;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            server_name domain.com;

            if ($allow = no) {
            return 403;
            }
            if ($bad_referer) {
            return 444;
            }



            location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
            }

            client_body_buffer_size 124K;

            client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 100m;

        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

        error_page 404 /404.html;



        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types application/json application/x-javascript application/xml text/javascript text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;

        # Rewrites for Yoast SEO XML Sitemap
        rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
        include hhvm.conf;
        #       include domain.com-ps.conf;
        include multisite.conf;
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$server_name$uri/ permanent;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

         if ($bad_client) { return 403; }



        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        }
}
```

And this is Varnish .vlc

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import directors;

backend server1 {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";             # IP or Hostname of backend
  .port = "8081";                  # Port Apache or whatever is listening
  .max_connections = 800;          # That's it
  .first_byte_timeout = 300s;      # How long to wait before we receive a first byte from our backend?
  .connect_timeout = 300s;         # How long to wait for a backend connection?
  .between_bytes_timeout = 300s;   # How long to wait between bytes received from our backend?
}

# Only allow purging from specific IPs
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
    "domain.com";
}

sub vcl_init {
  # Called when VCL is loaded, before any requests pass through it. Typically used to initialize VMODs.
  new vdir = directors.round_robin();
  vdir.add_backend(server1);
  #vdir.add_backend(server2);
  #vdir.add_backend(server3);
}


sub vcl_recv {
  # Called at the beginning of a request, after the complete request has been received and parsed.
  # Its purpose is to decide whether or not to serve the request, how to do it, and, if applicable,
  # which backend to use.
  # also used to modify the request

  # send all traffic to the vdir director
  set req.backend_hint = vdir.backend();

  # TURN OFF CACHE when needed (just uncomment this only when needed)
  # return(pass);

  # Allow purging from ACL
  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
    return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
    }
    return (purge);
  }


  # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
  set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

  # set or append the client.ip to X-Forwarded-For header. Important for logging and correct IPs.
  if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
  }

###
### Do not Cache: special cases
###

  # Do not cache AJAX requests.
    if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
        return(pass);
    }

  # Post requests will not be cached
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
        return (pass);
    }

  # Only cache GET or HEAD requests. This makes sure the POST requests are always passed.
  #if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
  #  return (pass);
  #}

  # Dont Cache WordPress post pages and edit pages
    if (req.url ~ "(wp-admin|post\.php|edit\.php|wp-login)") {
        return(pass);
    }
    if (req.url ~ "/wp-cron.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
        return (pass);
    }

  # Woocommerce 
    if (req.url ~ "(cart|my-account|checkout|addons)") {
        return (pass);
    }
    if ( req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
        return (pass);
    }

  # Paid memberships Pro PMP
    if ( req.url ~ "(membership-account|membership-checkout)" ) {
        return (pass);
    }

  # WordPress Social Login Plugin. Note: Need to develop this. Please share if you have an example.
    if (req.url ~ "(wordpress-social-login|wp-social-login)") {
        return (pass);
    }

  # WP-Affiliate
    if ( req.url ~ "\?ref=" ) {
        return (pass);
    }

  # phpBB Logged in users and ACP
    if ( req.url ~ "(/forumPM/adm/|ucp.php?mode=|\?mode=edit)" ) {
        return (pass);
    }


###
###    http header Cookie
###    Remove some cookies (if found)
###    Cache This Stuff
###
# https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.html#cookies

  ### COOKIE MADNESS.

    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp test cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the phpBB cookie. This will help us cache bots and anonymous users.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "style_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "phpbb3_psyfx_track=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the cloudflare cookie 
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__cfduid=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the PHPSESSID in members area cookie 
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "PHPSESSID=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
    }

  # MEGA DROP. Drop ALL cookies sent to WordPress, except those originating from the URLs defined.
  # This increases HITs significantly, but be careful it can also break plugins that need cookies.
  # Note: The /members/ directory had problems with PMP login and social login plugin. 
  # Adding it to the exclude list here (and including it below in the "Retain cookies" list) fixed login.
  # This works better than than other cookie removal examples found on varnish's website.
  # Note phpBB directory (forumPM) also passes cookies here.
  if (!(req.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|cart|my-account|checkout|addons|wordpress-social-login|wp-login\.php|forumPM|members)")) {
  unset req.http.cookie;
  }

  # Normalize the query arguments. 
  # Note: Placing this above the "do not cache" section breaks some WP theme elements and admin functionality.
  set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

  # Large static files are delivered directly to the end-user without
  # waiting for Varnish to fully read the file first.
  # Varnish 4 fully supports Streaming, so see do_stream in vcl_backend_response() to witness the glory.
  if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(mp[34]|rar|tar|tgz|wav|zip|bz2|xz|7z|avi|mov|ogm|mpe?g|mk[av])(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  }

  # Cache all static files by Removing all cookies for static files
  # Remember, do you really need to cache static files that don't cause load? Only if you have memory left.
  # Here I decide to cache these static files. For me, most of them are handled by the CDN anyway.
  if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(bmp|bz2|css|doc|eot|flv|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|pdf|png|rtf|swf|txt|woff|xml)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  }

  # Cache all static files by Removing all cookies for static files - These file extensions are generated by WP Super Cache.
  if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(html|htm|gz)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  }

  # Do not cache Authorized requests.
    if (req.http.Authorization) {
        return(pass);
    }

 # Cache all others requests. 
 # Note Varnish v4: vcl_recv must now return hash instead of lookup
    return (hash);
}


sub vcl_pipe {
  # Called upon entering pipe mode.
  # In this mode, the request is passed on to the backend, and any further data from both the client
  # and backend is passed on unaltered until either end closes the connection. Basically, Varnish will
  # degrade into a simple TCP proxy, shuffling bytes back and forth. For a connection in pipe mode,
  # no other VCL subroutine will ever get called after vcl_pipe.

  # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
  # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
  # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
  # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
  # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
  # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.

  # set bereq.http.Connection = "Close";

  return (pipe);
}


sub vcl_pass {
  # Called upon entering pass mode. In this mode, the request is passed on to the backend, and the
  # backend's response is passed on to the client, but is not entered into the cache. Subsequent
  # requests submitted over the same client connection are handled normally.

  # return (pass);
}


# The data on which the hashing will take place
sub vcl_hash {
  # Called after vcl_recv to create a hash value for the request. This is used as a key
  # to look up the object in Varnish.

  hash_data(req.url);

  if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
  } else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
  }

  # hash cookies for requests that have them
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    hash_data(req.http.Cookie);
  }

  # If the client supports compression, keep that in a different cache
  if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
      hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
  }

  return (lookup);
}


# Handle the HTTP request coming from our backend
sub vcl_backend_response {
  # Called after the response headers has been successfully retrieved from the backend.

  # Sometimes, a 301 or 302 redirect formed via Apache's mod_rewrite can mess with the HTTP port that is being passed along.
  # This often happens with simple rewrite rules in a scenario where Varnish runs on :80 and Apache on :8080 on the same box.
  # A redirect can then often redirect the end-user to a URL on :8080, where it should be :80.
  # This may need fine tuning on your setup.
  # To prevent accidental replace, we only filter the 301/302 redirects for now.
  if (beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
    set beresp.http.Location = regsub(beresp.http.Location, ":[0-9]+", "");
  }

###
### Overall TTL
### Note: The TTL is designed to be somewhat aggressive here, to keep things in cache.
###
  # Lets get this party started.
  # This will keep things in cache longer
  if (beresp.ttl > 0s) {
  unset beresp.http.expires;
  set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age=900";
  set beresp.ttl = 4d; # how long you cache objects
  set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";
  }

  # Allow stale content, in case the backend goes down.
  # make Varnish keep all objects for x hours beyond their TTL
  set beresp.grace = 12h;

###
### Static Files
###
  # Enable cache for all static files
  # Monitor your cache size, if you get data nuked out of it, consider giving up the static file cache.
  # More reading here: https://ma.ttias.be/stop-caching-static-files/
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(bmp|bz2|css|doc|eot|flv|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mp[34]|pdf|png|rar|rtf|swf|tar|tgz|txt|wav|woff|xml|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    set beresp.ttl = 2d; # set a TTL for these optional.
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }

  # Cache all static files by Removing all cookies for static files - Note: These file extensions are generated by WordPress WP Super Cache.
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(html|htm|gz)(\?.*)?$") {
    set beresp.ttl = 1d; # set a TTL for these optional.
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }

###
### Targeted TTL
###
  # Members section is very dynamic and uses cookies (see cookie settings in vcl_recv). 
  if (bereq.url ~ "/members/") {
    set beresp.ttl = 2d;
  }
  # My Shop section is fairly static when browsing the catalog, but woocommerce is passed in vcl_recv. 
  if (bereq.url ~ "/psyshop/") {
    set beresp.ttl = 1d;
  }
  # phBB Forum
  # Note: Cookies are dropped for phpBB in vcl_recv which disables the forums cookies, however, logged in users still get a hash.
  # I set the anonymous user as a bot in phpBB admin settings. As bots dont use cookies, this gives 99% hit rate.
  if (bereq.url ~ "/forumPM/") {
    set beresp.ttl = 2h;
  }
  # Long ttl sites
  if (bereq.url ~ "(example.com|example2.com)") {
    set beresp.ttl = 1w;
  }

  # Large static files are delivered directly to the end-user without
  # waiting for Varnish to fully read the file first.
  # Varnish 4 fully supports Streaming, so use streaming here to avoid locking.
  # I do not stream large files from my server, I use a CDN or dropbox, so I have not tested this.
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(mp[34]|rar|tar|tgz|wav|zip|bz2|xz|7z|avi|mov|ogm|mpe?g|mk[av])(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.do_stream = true;  # Check memory usage it'll grow in fetch_chunksize blocks (128k by default) if the backend doesn't send a Content-Length header, so only enable it for big objects
    set beresp.do_gzip = false;   # Don't try to compress it for storage
  }

  # don't cache response to posted requests or those with basic auth
  if ( bereq.method == "POST" || bereq.http.Authorization ) {
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    set beresp.ttl = 120s;
    return (deliver);
        }

  return (deliver);
}


# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
# Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
sub vcl_deliver {
  # Called before a cached object is delivered to the client.

  if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }

  # Please note that obj.hits behaviour changed in 4.0, now it counts per objecthead, not per object
  # and obj.hits may not be reset in some cases where bans are in use. See bug 1492 for details.
  # So take hits with a grain of salt
  set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;

  # Remove some headers: PHP version
   unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

  # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
  unset resp.http.Server;
  unset resp.http.X-Drupal-Cache;
  unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
  unset resp.http.Age;
  unset resp.http.Via;
  unset resp.http.Link;
  unset resp.http.X-Generator;

  if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
  unset resp.http.magicmarker;
  set resp.http.age = "0";
  }

  return (deliver);
}



sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 720) {
    # We use this special error status 720 to force redirects with 301 (permanent) redirects
    # To use this, call the following from anywhere in vcl_recv: return (synth(720, "http://host/new.html"));
    set resp.http.Location = resp.reason;
    set resp.status = 301;
    return (deliver);
  } elseif (resp.status == 721) {
    # And we use error status 721 to force redirects with a 302 (temporary) redirect
    # To use this, call the following from anywhere in vcl_recv: return (synth(720, "http://host/new.html"));
    set resp.http.Location = resp.reason;
    set resp.status = 302;
    return (deliver);
  }

  return (deliver);
}


sub vcl_fini {
  # Called when VCL is discarded only after all requests have exited the VCL.
  # Typically used to clean up VMODs.

  return (ok);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After quite a lot of struggle, I found the solution, add this fastcgi param on your hhvm / php-fpm locations

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

Check here for another example : [nginx > varnish > hhvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/670620/nginx-varnish-hhvm?rq=1)

Comment: What file did you change to add this param in your "hhvm / php-fpm:" locations?